# angularjs repeat not working

Tags: json, angularjs

I have angularjs setup with routes and I am having some problems with ng-repeat. Here is the code I have in my view

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Home Page</h1>

    <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
<div>
    {{allApps}}
</div>
<div ng-repeat="app in allApps">
    <p>Here {{ app }}</p>
</div>
```

Everything above the ng-repeat is showing. The allApps above is showing my json object. Maybe it could be how I am building my json. Here is what the json looks like

```
[{"id":"1","app_name":"Disconnect Search (Beta)","app_url":"https:\/\/play.google.com\/store\/apps\/details?id=me.disconnect.search","app_provider":"D2d","app_price":"Free","app_image_url":"https:\/\/lh5.ggpht.com\/j4Wagvv21vGD5F3oU_cl4LZWJnBLVR4ElKFsw9xuNaF0P96VFvTJY3v_nXZNcBkEqQ=w300-rw","app_show_number":"170"},{"id":"2","app_name":"Nmb3rs - numbers in words","app_url":"https:\/\/play.google.com\/store\/apps\/details?id=com.funnygerman.nmbrs","app_provider":"EricA","app_price":"Free","app_image_url":"https:\/\/lh4.ggpht.com\/uMN0q1f2BsHVt4p0qHlhsrcFCgF201VaTRSJOiDf_mxzx3eUzGhBnkB0wWzzLrlszNUR=w300-rw","app_show_number":"170"},{"id":"3","app_name":"Mountains Now Free Wallpaper","app_url":"https:\/\/play.google.com\/store\/apps\/details?id=com.intcast.livecinemagraph.gnrockymountains","app_provider":"EricA","app_price":"Free","app_image_url":"https:\/\/lh6.ggpht.com\/cXpCAtTuNBeFZIy3ntMOERI8WCnQ3N8i3YhE_KI8TdH4AwSpJYxzDRi-204MDUwGxBkm=w300-rw","app_show_number":"169"}]
```

I am building this json using json_encode from a mysql statement. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You may want `<p>Here {{ app.app_name }}</p>` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

allApps is probably a string instead of an object. Throw a $scope.allApps = angular.fromJson($scope.allApps); in there somewhere.

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I will add answer when stack allows me to